# how to call a event in the dialogflow v2 :nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I'm using dialogflow v2 using npm. I just want call a `welcome` event in dialogflow. How can I do it in the nodejs. I'm pretty new to it.
This is my code

```
const projectId = "xxxxxx";
  const LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US';
  const sessionId = req.body.sessionId;
  var query = req.body.query;

  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId,sessionId);
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: query,
        languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE,
      },
    },
  };

  sessionClient.detectIntent(request).then(response => {
    console.log('intent detected');
    const result = response[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);

    if(result.fulfillmentText) {
      console.log(result.fulfillmentText);
      return res.json({reply: result.fulfillmentText})
    }
    // if(result.intent) {
    //   console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`)
    // }
    else {
      console.log('no intent found');
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('error '+err);
  })
```

As I open the chat page I just want to throw a welcome message. In order to do that, i read that i have to call the event. How can I do that? I have taken the reference from [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow)

Answer (score 5):

The Request body should be like this:

```
let eventName='WELCOME';  //name of the event

 let request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
          event: {
            name: eventName,  
            languageCode: 'en-US'
          },
        },
      };
```

checkout- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.js#L96

let me know if you find any difficulties :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `actions-on-google` as it is much easier to build nodejs backend for dialogflow link : [actions on google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs)

And for sample project refer [Number genie project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs)

Hope this would help you.

Comment: where is code in genie demo app to call an event? eg something like `conv.event('EVT')`

Comment: In `number-genie` they have used `conv.contexts` context based approach , so the intents are triggered by context set , for event based intent triggering you can trigger events too  but u will need `dialogflow-fulfillment` library for event based approach i guess , Hope this helps you.

Comment: `const {
  WebhookClient
} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


const agent = new WebhookClient({
  request,
  response
});

//with data
agent.setFollowupEvent({
  "event": {
    "name": 'StartGame',
    "data": {
      'type': 'test'
    }
  }
});

//direct trigger
agent.setFollowupEvent('StartGame');
`
Hope this works.